# What to do when one has only a little reputation and wants to put a bounty on a question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

What if some new user has a good question and is using Stack Overflow for the first time (no rep). He does not get his answer for some days and wants to put a bounty on his question. What should he do?

What if he puts a link to his question on Meta Stack Overflow and asks for help there? Will he downvoted and will his question be "[CLOSED]"?

Comment: To put on a bounty themselves, they'll have to wait until they have the reputation. But if it's a really good question, do add a link here. (No one can make any guarantees as to how people are going to vote on it, though)

Comment: That user can take the [tour] to learn how to earn some reputation on a Stack Exchange site. For example: the user can choose to answer questions and if it is a good answer, somebody with 15+ points would be able to upvote it and possibly will do it. That user can begin proposing substantial edits to new posts. Each approved edit would give +2 points. That user can look through questions under bounty tab to earn some good amount of points in less time (expect difficulty).

Comment: This question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356055/select-single-box-and-add-css-to-it

Comment: If you don't get answers for days, your question probably is not answerable. No bounty is going to change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user will have to wait until they have enough points to add a bounty.
The user can also hope that someone else will put a bounty on their question, but that is a small chance.

One can earn points by asking good questions, answering questions, and making substantial, good edits.

Another option is to gain 200 points on another Stack Exchange site, so that you will earn the 100 point association bonus. You can only gain this bonus once, though, so if you want to spend it on a bounty, use it wisely!

You can also draw attention to the question on social media - using the "Share" button below a post to share it on Twitter, Facebook or Google+ . You can also post the link on LinkedIn, or another medium where you believe the question to be relevant.

Drawing attention to one's question on Meta, just to get more views, is abusing Meta. While it *might* get the question more attention, it is not what Meta is meant for. The post on Meta would probably be downvoted and removed.
What would happen to the post on the main site is anyone's guess. It is possible that the post gets more attention and upvotes. But it's *far* more likely that vigilante meta users will downvote the SO question as a "punishment". They would be wrong in doing so, because votes must be on the post, not on the user. But it is a likely outcome.

Comment: I would say there is also a high change that Meta will correctly vote on the content, and the result may be downvotes and/or closure.